# How to disable button with ng-disabled in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

how can I write condition like disable button if `$scope.status=true`
I tried something like this- `ng-disabled="callStatus==true"`
But it didn't worked what wrong I am doing here? please help

Comment: in your condition you have callStatus but your variable is status

Comment: You need to give us a minimal, reproducible example.